# How to add commas after double quotes in string PHP?

Tags: php

I have string like below - and want to add comma after each double quotes in my string

```
"200728J70JNY08""200728JQ05Y4S4""200730QWVD1DDQ""200728H2QS7M9Y"
```

I want to :

```
"200728J70JNY08","200728JQ05Y4S4","200730QWVD1DDQ","200728H2QS7M9Y"
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? The code which we can help you with if it's not working?

Comment: Please include the actual PHP script so that we may see the literal string in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace`

```
$Str = '"200728J70JNY08""200728JQ05Y4S4""200730QWVD1DDQ""200728H2QS7M9Y"';
$result = str_replace('""', '","', $Str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could accomplish that using str_replace.

Example:

```
$original_string = '"200728J70JNY08""200728JQ05Y4S4""200730QWVD1DDQ""200728H2QS7M9Y"';

$after = str_replace('"', ";", $original_string);
echo $after_v2 = str_replace(';;', ";", $after);
```